# Winzip Theme for WPF

Tags: wpf, user-interface, modern-ui

The Winzip theme is Modern UI. But it looks like a shared theme

Winzip:
[image: Winzip Theme]

Advanced Installer
[image: Advanced Installer Theme]

SmartFTP
[image: Smart FTP Theme]

Also I looked at these themes
[MahApps Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)
[Modern UI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui)
But these application themes are not them. So what is they theme? And with witch program they created these?

Comment: fluent ribbon https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon is said to have a metro style. You may want to check that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if these are the exact icons, but they look very similar:
[Axialis Pure Flat Icons](http://www.axialis.com/stock-icons/pure-flat-2013-toolbar.html)

However, they're *very* expensive.

Also, not sure about any of the other controls on the interface, but these look like they'd be similar as well (look at the Themes tab):
[DevExpress WPF Controls](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/)